# Misalignment in table cell next to each other in HTML emails (Outlook 2007/10)

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

I've encountered an issue in Outlook 2007/10 when I place 2 table cells next to each other that don't have the same height content. This is what I want to see:

http://cl.ly/image/0047161T2t3d

But in Outlook 2007/10. I am getting this:

http://cl.ly/image/142b43072u1l

Here is the snippet of code in question:

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" height="417">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <a href="http://www.kelloggs.com/en_US/the-benefits-of-cereal/fiber-and-whole-grains.html?version=_TRACKINGCODE__&PID=_PID__&utm_source=newsletter042814&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_learn_more_button_section&utm_campaign=KNA_SPKOPI_CINCORECIPES_0428" reportname="sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_learn_more_button_section"><img src="http://img.ed4.net/kelloggs/images/KNA/2014_0428_spkopi_cinco/sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_header.jpg" width="320" height="122" alt="Don&rsquo;t Forget the Fiber" title="Don&rsquo;t Forget the Fiber" style="display:block; border:0px; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="20"></td>
                    <td width="300" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #776f67; line-height: 18px;">
                        <div><span style="color: #e00034; line-height: 14px; font-weight: bold;">Did you know that 9 out of 10 people fall short on fiber?</span><sup style="font-size: 11px;">1</sup> This quick-to-make <a href="https://www.kelloggsfamilyrewards.com/en_US/recipes/chipotle-bean-burritos.html?version=_TRACKINGCODE__&PID=_PID__&utm_source=newsletter042814&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=sec_dw_recipes_cincodemayo_0428_chipotle_bean_burritos_image&utm_campaign=KNA_SPKOPI_CINCORECIPES_0428" reportname="sec_dw_recipes_cincodemayo_0428_chipotle_bean_burritos_image" style="color: #96172e;">Nectarine-Broccoli Salad</a> is packed with flavor, vibrant fruits and veggies, and <em>Kellogg&rsquo;s</em>&reg; <em>All-Bran</em>&reg; Original cereal, offering a whopping total of 7 grams of fiber. That&rsquo;s more than 25% of your daily value per serving!
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td height="10"></td></tr></table>

                        Adding a variety of fiber-full foods to your day not only tastes great, but offers good-for-you nutrition. Be sure to look for foods and recipes with a good source of fiber that contain at least 3 grams of fiber per serving.</div>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td height="15"></td></tr></table>

                        <div><a href="http://www.kelloggs.com/en_US/the-benefits-of-cereal/fiber-and-whole-grains.html?version=_TRACKINGCODE__&PID=_PID__&utm_source=newsletter042814&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_learn_more_button_section&utm_campaign=KNA_SPKOPI_CINCORECIPES_0428" reportname="sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_learn_more_button_section"><img src="http://img.ed4.net/kelloggs/images/KNA/2014_general/learnmore_btn.gif" width="160" height="31" alt="Learn More" title="Learn More" style="display:block; border:0px; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></a></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" height="417">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <img src="http://img.ed4.net/kelloggs/images/KNA/2014_0428_spkopi_cinco/sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_nectarine_broccoli_salad_header.jpg" width="320" height="69" alt="Fiber Is Fabulous in Nectarine-Broccoli Salad" title="Fiber Is Fabulous in Nectarine-Broccoli Salad" style="display:block; border:0px; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <a href="https://www.kelloggsfamilyrewards.com/en_US/recipes/nectarine-broccoli-salad.html?version=_TRACKINGCODE__&PID=_PID__&utm_source=newsletter042814&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_nectarine_broccoli_salad_image&utm_campaign=KNA_SPKOPI_CINCORECIPES_0428" reportname="sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_nectarine_broccoli_salad_image"><img src="http://img.ed4.net/kelloggs/images/KNA/2014_0428_spkopi_cinco/sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_nectarine_broccoli_salad_image.jpg" width="320" height="240" alt="Nectarine-Broccoli Salad" title="Nectarine-Broccoli Salad" style="display:block; border:0px; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="170" align="right" valign="top">
                        <a href="https://www.kelloggsfamilyrewards.com/en_US/recipes/nectarine-broccoli-salad.html?version=_TRACKINGCODE__&PID=_PID__&utm_source=newsletter042814&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_nectarine_broccoli_salad_get_recipe_button&utm_campaign=KNA_SPKOPI_CINCORECIPES_0428" reportname="sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_nectarine_broccoli_salad_get_recipe_button"><img src="http://img.ed4.net/kelloggs/images/KNA/2014_general/get_recipe_button.jpg" width="160" height="31" alt="Get Recipe" title="Get Recipe" style="display:block; border:0px; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="92" align="right" valign="top">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kelloggsfamilyrewards.com%2Fen_US%2Frecipes%2Fnectarine-broccoli-salad.html%23.UzrYUoIQm40.facebook&p[title]=Nectarine-Broccoli%20Salad&display=popup&version=_TRACKINGCODE__&PID=_PID__&utm_source=newsletter042814&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_nectarine_broccoli_salad_facebook_sharing&utm_campaign=KNA_SPKOPI_CINCORECIPES_0428" reportname="sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_nectarine_broccoli_salad_facebook_sharing"><img src="http://img.ed4.net/kelloggs/images/KNA/2014_general/facebook_share.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook" style="display:block; border:0px; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="24" align="right" valign="top">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Nectarine-Broccoli+Salad&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kelloggsfamilyrewards.com%2Fen_US%2Frecipes%2Fnectarine-broccoli-salad.html%23.UzrYvSBVfJc.twitter&related=&version=_TRACKINGCODE__&PID=_PID__&utm_source=newsletter042814&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_nectarine_broccoli_salad_twitter_sharing&utm_campaign=KNA_SPKOPI_CINCORECIPES_0428" reportname="sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_nectarine_broccoli_salad_twitter_sharing"><img src="http://img.ed4.net/kelloggs/images/KNA/2014_general/twitter_share.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter" style="display:block; border:0px; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="25" align="right" valign="top">
                        <a href="http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?media=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kelloggsfamilyrewards.com%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Fcommon%2Frecipes%2FNectarineBroccoliSalad_5724.jpg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kelloggsfamilyrewards.com%2Fen_US%2Frecipes%2Fnectarine-broccoli-salad.html&description=Nectarine-Broccoli%20Salad&version=_TRACKINGCODE__&PID=_PID__&utm_source=newsletter042814&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_nectarine_broccoli_salad_pinterest_sharing&utm_campaign=KNA_SPKOPI_CINCORECIPES_0428" reportname="sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_nectarine_broccoli_salad_pinterest_sharing"><img src="http://img.ed4.net/kelloggs/images/KNA/2014_general/pinterest_share.jpg" width="20" height="20" alt="Pinterest" title="Pinterest" style="display:block; border:0px; padding:0px; margin:0px;"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="9"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <img src="http://img.ed4.net/kelloggs/images/KNA/2014_0428_spkopi_cinco/sec_dw_recipe_nutritioncorner_allbran_0428_nectarine_broccoli_salad_footer.jpg" width="320" height="77" alt="1 Moshfegh A, Goldman J, Cleveland L. What We Eat in America, NHANES 2001-2002: Usual Nutrient Intake From Foods as Compared to Dietary Reference Intakes. U.S. Department of Agriculture, Agricultural Research Service, 2005." title="1 Moshfegh A, Goldman J, Cleveland L. What We Eat in America, NHANES 2001-2002: Usual Nutrient Intake From Foods as Compared to Dietary Reference Intakes. U.S. Department of Agriculture, Agricultural Research Service, 2005." style="display:block; border:0px; padding:0px; margin:0px;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it could be the Outlook page break issue. Because Outlook '07/'10/'13 use the MS Word render engine, it forces page breaks into your code.

[Here you can find](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/horizontal_spacing_issues_in_outlook_2007_and_2010) more on the issue and some suggested solutions.